# Armadillo save double precision ascii

Tags: c++, armadillo

I'd like to save some complex double precision matrices in ascii format with the armadillo library, but somehow only 6 significant digits get saved... I know this truncation (or rounding, haven't checked) can be overcome by using binary formats, but I want to use ascii so that I can verify and modify some values by hand.
In the mwe provided below I would expect that matrices A and C are the same for about 16 significant digits. Is there a secret switch to tell armadillo to save complex matrices in ascii format with higher precision? Thanks

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{
cout.precision(20);
cx_mat A = randu<cx_mat>(2,2);
A(0,0) = 1.2345678901234567890;
A.raw_print(cout);
A.save("A.arma_ascii", arma_ascii);
cout << endl;
cx_mat C;
C.load("A.arma_ascii", arma_ascii);
C.raw_print(cout);
return 0;
}
```

**EDIT** The problem only occurs for complex matrices. For real ones armadillo sets the precision in diskio_meat.hpp. Seems like the only way to get around this limitation is to either patch armadillo or save complex and imaginary part seperately.

**EDIT 2** Issue got solved in armadillo library ([git commit](https://github.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code/commit/86b29aa5b3406b0dc56db4f6f294a6427edcc109)), just 2 hours after posting my question here. Great work!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the underlying data type for `cx_mat` is `complex<double>` so you can not expect more than 15-17 significant decimal digits precision, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format. 
In the Armadillo code they use `std::ofstream` as output and the default is to display 6 digits, as you have in your A.arma_ascii file.

Comment: Your answer does not quite solve my problem, but pointed me towards the right direction. Seems like armadillo sets the precision for ascii output only for real matrices, not for complex ones, thus I get stuck with 6 digits. See also diskio_meat.hpp in armadillo library.